# is possible to insert item into map if it does not exist and otherwise increment its occurrence in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a shopping cart controller in dart/flutter with GetX statemanager. I have two different arrays with the same items. When a product is added to the cart, i want to first check if the item exists in a map. If so, i increment its occurrence, otherwise its added. The problem is that this only works for each product array separately.

E.g Array1 -> add item in Array1 to cart. this works perfectly;

Array2 -> add item in Array2 to cart. this also works perfectly.

Array1 and Array2 contain the same items;

Now if i want to add a product to the cart that has allready been added by the other array, it adds as a new entry instead of incrementing its occurrence.

code:

```
  Product product1 = Product(id: 1, title: 'title - 1');
  Product product2 = Product(id: 1, title: 'title - 1');

  int count = 0;

  while (count < 10) {
    addToMap(product1);
    addToMap(product2);

    count++;
  }

addToMap(Product product) {
  if (hashMap.containsKey(product)) {
    hashMap[product] += 1;
  } else {
    hashMap[product] = 1;
  }
}

 hashMap.forEach((key, value) {
    print('key is ${key.title} and value is ${value}');
  });
```

output:

```
key is title - 1 and value is 10
key is title - 1 and value is 10
```

expected output should be the following

```
key is title - 1 and value is 20
```

Comment: Maybe consider using a `Map` or a `List` of `Lists` containing a product. A more elegant solution would be to have a class store a product in the shopping cart and have a `count` variable inside of it. Then have an increment and decrement method inside of that class. When adding an item to the cart, check if that product already exists and if it doesn't, add it, if it does, then call that item's increment method.

Comment: You can simplify `addToMap` with `void addToMap(Product product) => (hashMap[product] ??= 0) += 1;`.  Regarding your problem with two “arrays“, it probably would help if you explained what the difference is between them.  Why do you have two?

Comment: I am using a fakestore api that only has 20 products. so to somewhat populate the app page, i have to reuse some data. My problem is not with the data in the arrays, those are identical. the problem is that the AddToMap() function should only add products if its not already in the map, otherwise increment its occurrence, but it doesn't. This also happens if i add the same product into the map from a different page. so shopping page, search page, favorites page, etc...

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your hashMap is the key. product1 and product2 are 2 different instances, that mean 2 different keys. Instead of using the whole class, try using only the id. It should look something like this:

```
 addToMap(Product product) {
  if (hashMap.containsKey(product.id)) {
    hashMap[product.id] += 1;
  } else {
    hashMap[product.id] = 1;
  }
}
```

this way even if the instances are different, the id will be the same.

Comment: Thanks so much. its no really the right solution but it let me to right solution.

Comment: Alternatively override `Product.operator ==` and `Product.hashCode` to use `product.id`.

Comment: @CSharpstudent You should explain what you did so that anyone else who encounters the same problem could benefit.

Comment: i added the answer. see below!

Answer (score -1):

Correct solution is as follows.

as suggested by @Razvan. i did use the product.id as the key in the hashmap. this solution works well, but if your like me and you want to be able to extract objects from from the ints in the hashmap. you have to use a List. the list holds each item only once. the hashmap keeps track of how many times an item is added to the list. and if you wan to be able to calculate price for example, use a simple loop over the hashmap and mutiply price by quantity.

```
Map hashMap = HashMap<int, int>();
List<T> products = <T>();

//calculate price for a item
hashMap.forEach((key, value) {
      print('Key is $key and value is $value');
      for (var element in products) {
        print('Price is ${element.price * value}');
      }
    });

addToMap(Product product) {
  if (hashMap.containsKey(product.id)) {
    hashMap[product.id] += 1;
  } else {
    products.add(product)
    hashMap[product.id] = 1;
  }
```